# Java 8 Commiting anonymous functions

Tags: java

I try to update my knowledge with the new funktionalities of Java 1.8.
I am working a lot with streams but in some cases I am not sure if there are new features solving my problems.

Maybee someone could look at the following working example (its about old itext):

```
public static Document createListingPDF(List<PdfPageData> pages, String file)
{
    return createListing(PdfWriter.class, pages, file);
}

public static Document createListingRTF(List<PdfPageData> pages, String file)
{
    return createListing(RtfWriter2.class, pages, file);
}

private static Document createListing(Object ident, List<PdfPageData> pages, String file)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        if(ident == PdfWriter.class)
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        if(ident == RtfWriter2.class)
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return document;
}
```

My aim WITH Java 8 would be to commit a kind of Funktion to "createListing" containing "any" Writer-Class and executing the "getInstance" with the document inside the method.

It is just a brainstorming how to handle it. :)
(I do not want to move the init of document to the two calling methods (think about duplicated code)

The benefit will be clear, if you have more calling methods which whould increase the try block with its Class-checks.

Hope I described good enought to lead the discussion the way I thought about the gordian knot in my head :P

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is not Java 8 feature. It's plain old polymorphism.

Make PdfWriter and RtfWriter2 implement the same `DocumentWriter` interface, and pass a `DocumentWriter` to your `createListing` method; Something like the following:

```
public static Document createListingPDF(List<PdfPageData> pages, String file) {
    return createListing(new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)), pages);
}

public static Document createListingRTF(List<PdfPageData> pages, String file) {
    return createListing(new RtfWriter2(new FileOutputStream(file)), pages)
}

private static Document createListing(DocumentWriter writer, List<PdfPageData> pages) {
    Document document = new Document(pages);
    writer.write(document);
    return document;
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought. But the Writer are from lib/itext-2.1.7.jar and lib/itext-rtf-2.1.7.jar and do not implement any common interface for that.

Comment: The write an Adapter class for both, which implements the Writer interface and delegates to the native writer from the library.